# spark jdbc conectivity from edgenode Jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, jupyter-notebook

I need to create a dataframe using jdbc connectivity to Oracle database. I am using a Jupyter notebook from edgenode to do this connectivity. Spark is running in client mode from Jupyter notebook. Database host and port doesnt have a connectivity from edgenode, but it is open from datanodes. But when I am trying to create dataframe, it is failing because of "connect timed out" error. Is it normal? I think it is trying to establish a connection from edgenode where connectivity cannot be established? How can I make sure that connectivity happens from executors (according to me, this is how it should be in theory).

Answer (score 1):

It is "normal". In general driver node (in your case edge node) has to have the same access to data, as any worker node. While data loading is handled by executors, driver handles things like metadata (in your case fetching and translating schema) and computing splits (not relevant here).

Comment: okay. Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to launch Jupyter notebook in cluster mode then? So that my driver gets launched on some other node which has connectivity towards database?

Comment: I don't have answer to that. As far as I know, there isn't - cluster mode is not designed for interactive process - but in theory you could try to spawn a notebook server from the script. Then you'd of course face a problem of finding on which node it actually runs, and possibly mapping the ports.